# Search bar not working

Tags: bug, help-center

In the [How to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) section of the Help Center, the search bar does not work. The only way to make it work is by typing in it and then clicking on **advanced search**.

Also, if it worked, 3 links in the same paragraph would link to [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=). Which is a little too much in my opinion. [image]

I suggest that :

- We fix the search bar.
- We write *thoroughly searched for an answer* as plain text instead of link. (Or link to google ^_^)
- Make advanced search link to a advanced search page (whatever that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's meant to be a link to the *actual* search page, which this page obviously is not. I don't really see any problem with it being there.
2. Well, of course it only works if you actually type something. It loads an inline box directly below that when you click the Search button (the same thing you'd see as you were typing a question title on the Ask screen). So if you don't enter anything, obviously it won't load any questions below that... That particular search box does not jump you to the search page.

   [image: Search on How to Ask]
3. Previously, the advanced search options used to come up on the page if you submitted an empty search. This is no longer the case. The advanced search options are always present on every search page by clicking the link at the right. That part should probably be removed.

Comment: -_- So you really implyied that I didn't type anything in the searchbar ? Well then it's not working in firefox 21.0

Comment: It uses the same thing as you see when typing a title on the Ask screen, except here you have to click the button first. It works fine for me on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: As for the advanced search URL updating as you type things in, it may be that the actual search works differently than that inline "may already have your answer" box that you see on the page, and is considered "more advanced" - but even then, I'd consider a different word there.